# Scatter Plot graph x axis Day of the week and Y axis Time

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the chart, I've to sort the x axis by 'Day' and plot the 'Time' values against Y axis. My goal is to show the Coorelation of Surge hour by hour and grouped by day(Monday - Sunday).

[Surge Occurence by Day and Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx0Ow.png)

[Surge Occurence by Date and Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWKNG.png)

Comment: Just to confirm, the x-axis is Day of Week (7 values) that would encompass a time-period of t. T-time could be a week, a month, a year, etc???? Depending on your data, that could be unreadable. Please elaborate on what a typical time-t represents and how many data points you expect. Also, let's pretend a single Sunday has 20 surges at varying times. Then the remainder of the month, there are just a couple surges on Sundays. Wouldn't the graph then show you that Sunday is a problem (when in reality it may not be because it had a problem just one day).

Answer (score 0):

Your data doesn't have dates (Friday, Saturday, etc are days not date) that is why Excel is not displaying the dates. When you insert dates, Excel will show them on the x-axis.

[image: x-axis showing dates on a scatter chart]

Comment: Thanks Reddy for your time. I've edited the query with my goal bit more clearly.I'm not sure how to sort the X axis Day - Monday and Sunday and adjust the grid line to show the points on line similar to what I got it for Date and Time.